# Use a sql database table properties to use as log In credentials for user in a web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller, where i have created a DataTable.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        string connString = "Data source=DEVELOPER1; Initial catalog=Temp;Integrated security=True";
        string commString = "";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            commString = "select * from usermaster";
            DataTable datatable = GetDataTable(commString);
            return View(datatable);
        }
        public DataTable GetDataTable(string strQuery)
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commString, conn))
            {
                    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    datatable.Load(sqlDataReader);
                }
            }
            return datatable;
        }
```

This is my view.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="text2" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button" onclick="button1_click()" />
```

Below is the screenshot of the query which I have used in **commString**.

[image]
And this is the image of the output of my current position of the project.

[image]

Now my requirement is if an user put "adm" in both of the text fields then it will display "true" in alert box, else it will display "false".
Even if the user left any one filed blank, then also it will display "false".
Please help.

Comment: Show us `Download` [Post] Action

Comment: You're passing the entire username+password list to the view (even if only one value) and you've tagged this jquery (despite having no javascript other than an ajax post).  Are you looking for some javascript to check the username+password and display an alert/messagebox?   Don't - that would be a *huge* security risk and pointless having a login.

Comment: This is just a prototype, i am in academic level. I just need to show the task done, to my faculty.

Comment: Even more reason to follow best practices / not demo/show code with massive security flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something like this might be what you're after

- don't pass the allowed logins+passwords to the view, anyone could do browser-view-source and see valid logins
- instead, pass the entered user+pass to the controller and check there
- use a POST as it's harder to intercept
- consider using an existing, built-in login mechanism such as Forms login

Client code:

```
 function button1_click() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Login",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            name: $('#text1').val(),
            password: $('#text2').val(),
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string name, string password)
    {
        commString = "select * from usermaster";
        DataTable datatable = GetDataTable(commString);

        // Check datatable contains name + password here
        bool found = ...

        return new JsonResult() { Data = found };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i am just checking strings with "adm" not from database

In View you need to write

```js
function button1_click() {
var url = '@Url.Action("Download","Home")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            name: $('#text1').val(),
            password: $('#text2').val(),
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

And in Controller

> 

```js
  public ActionResult Download(string text1, string text2)
        {
            if (text1 == null || text2 == null)
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                if (text1 == "adm" && text2 == "adm")
                {
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
```